# Sharepoint Server 2013 Hide/Show jquery/sputility not working on a New Item List Form -- no clue why (answered)

Tags: jquery

**The Point**
When someone chooses "One" as the value of the `urlTotal` column, it will hide `urlTwo` and `urlThree` columns. I pasted the script link from my site assets folder into a content editor in the DEFAULT NEW list template.
I placed the Content Editor UNDER the list form.

**The Fields**

- urlTotal (the display name is URL#) -- choice menu
- linkOne (the display name is URL1) -- hyperlink
- linkTwo (the display name is URL2) -- hyperlink
- linkThree (the display name is URL3) --hyperlink

**The Script**

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery/jquery1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/sputility/sputility.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var urlTotal = SPUtility.GetSPField('urlTotal');

var HideOrShowlinkTwoField=function(){
var urlTotalValue = urlTotal.GetValue();
if(urlTotalValue==='One')
{
SPUtility.GetSPField('linkTwo').Hide();
SPUtility.GetSPField('linkThree').Hide();
}
else
{
SPUtility.GetSPField('linkTwo').Show();
}
};
HideOrShowlinkTwoField();
$(urlTotal.Dropdown).on('change',HideOrShowlinkTwoField);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you check the developer console (f12) if you're getting any js error?

Comment: thanks for writing back -- I'm not totally sure what that means, though

Comment: Press F12 to open the developer console in your browser. Click on the console tab to view javascript errors (if any).

Comment: Ah. ok, Thanks. I deleted the query and restarted. I appreciate all of your help. Thanks!